Supabase sort / filter by relation count
I have the following query:
let query = supabase
      .from("property_owners")
      .select(
        `id, full_name,  property(id), address(id, street, house_number, city, zipcode, property(id))`,
      );

Now, I want to find a way to either:

Sort the property owners by property count
Filter the property owners by property count (get all property owners with > 5 properties)

I can't seem to find a way to do this, is this a limit of supabase?

You can always use views or rpcs to perform complicated queries instead of directly using the Supabase client library.
